# Can I configure an msi installer to remove any other installation with a different productcode but the same upgradecode before installation?

Tags: windows-installer

The remove previous versions property in the setup project doesn't quite work for me. I want the msi to also remove newer versions. Can I edit the msi database to tell it to remove all versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table. You can control which versions are removed from the VersionMin and VersionMax fields.

Comment: I set it so there is one entry in the upgrade table with actionproperty=PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED. Then I set version max in that record to be 999999.99. So basically now all my version numbers are 'previous versions' and it overwrites them. Thanks a bunch.