# VS Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, setup-project

I am creating a Visual Studio Setup project. I want to un-install another component from the system from the install of my component. The other component is installed from my own setup created using Visual Studio.

Currently when I am calling the un-install of the other component from the install action of the component I get the error code: 1618 (another MSI already running).

Could anyone suggest an alternative way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need custom actions for that, you can use built-in support from Windows Installer: 
[Can I configure an msi installer to remove any other installation with a different productcode but the same upgradecode before installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541903/can-i-configure-an-msi-installer-to-remove-any-other-installation-with-a-differe)

Answer (score 3):

you may add custom action but do remember add custom action in commit folder only .so that only after installation uninstall start